# "Outside the cell" or "outside of the cell"?

Tags: prepositions

What is more acceptable?

> There are more sodium ions *outside the* cell

or

> There are more sodium ions *outside* **of** *the* cell

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: There's also the possibility of *more sodium ions **on the** outside of the cell*, which would normally be taken to imply those additional ions are very close to (or "touching") the outer surface of the cell, as opposed to just anywhere (in the general vicinity). That "right next to the outer edge" sense might perhaps be more strongly suggested by your second example (including ***of***, but not ***on the***).

Answer (score 0):

> **outside the cell**
>   **outside of the cell**
>   **on the outside of the cell**

of these three only "*on the outside of the cell*" might imply direct contact with the cell wall.

Since you are probably talking about *osmotic pressure*, any of the three can be used without loss of understanding since the reader will probably already know how *osmotic pressure* works.